# ASP.NET, javascript: silly annoying apostrophe problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html-encode, apostrophe

I wanted to add a confirmation box to my ImageButton, so I have the following:

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm('OK to delete this district from the consultant\'s list?');");
```

But then .NET html-encodes the whole thing so it comes out in the HTML as:

```
onclick="return confirm(&#39;OK to delete this district from the consultant&#39;s list?&#39;);"
```

so the apostrophe in "consultant's" looks the same as the apostrophes surrounding the confirm parameter, and javascript gets all confused, and the confirm box does not come up.

Deleting the "consultant's" apostrophe solves the problem, but then I have an even more annoying punctuation error which is unacceptable.

What I seem to need is a "javascript" escape for the apostrophe, something that will escape the apostrophe only for javascript, not for HTML .. if that makes sense.

Any ideas??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "return confirm(\"OK to delete this district from the consultant\'s list?\");");
```

Escape `"` and use `confirm("...")`

Comment: There is no need to escape the single quote in this case. `"return confirm(\"OK to delete this district from the consultant's list?\");"` is sufficient.

Comment: @MattBall I'm being extra safe ;)

Comment: Oh, OK -- .NET html-encodes the quote so it comes out as onclick="return confirm(&quot;OK to delete this district from the consultant&#39;s list?&quot;);" I was afraid it was going to come out as onclick="return confirm("OK to delete this district from the consultant&#39;s list?");" which would cause quote-nested-inside-quote problems -- but of course, since it html-encoded the apostrophe, it would html-encode the quote. Thanks!