# submit button onclick javascript rendering diffrences from asp.net 2.0 to 4.0

Tags: javascript, asp.net, button, onclick

I have the following button in an ASP.Net web form:

```
<asp:Button id="btn_submit" text="Submit (Click only Once)" OnClick="process_form" runat="server" />
```

In the page code, I have the following function which is used
to disable multiple submits (this worked fine under ASP.Net 2.0) ...

```
private sub prevent_multiple_submits()

dim sb as StringBuilder

sb = New StringBuilder()

sb.Append( "this.value = 'Please wait...';this.disabled = true;" )
sb.Append( Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference( btn_submit, String.Empty ) )

btn_submit.Attributes.Add( "onclick", sb.ToString() )

end sub
```

When the page is run under ASP.Net 2.0 the HTML rendered is as follows (worked fine)...

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit (Click only Once)" onclick="this.value = 'Please wait...';this.disabled = true;__doPostBack('btn_submit','');" id="btn_submit" />
```

When the page is run under ASP.Net 4.0 the HTML rendered is as follows:

```
<input type="submit" name="btn_submit" value="Submit (Click only Once)" onclick="this.value = &#39;Please wait...&#39;;this.disabled = true;__doPostBack(&#39;btn_submit&#39;,&#39;&#39;);" language="javascript" id="btn_submit" />
```

... and for some reason, the button never appears as disabled ... (like it did under ASP.Net 2.0) ...

The form still submits and everything works -- but the button NEVER APPEARS DISABLED after being clicked on ?!

Has anyone else dealt with this behaviour ??  .. and if so, did you find a solution without resorting to altering web.config, using JQuery, etc.

BTW,

I did find the following references; but nothing has worked yet for me under ASP.Net 4.0.

[ASP.NET, javascript: silly annoying apostrophe problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834461/asp-net-javascript-silly-annoying-apostrophe-problem)

[HTMLEncode/HTMLDecode and the apostrophe ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14207328/htmlencode-htmldecode-and-the-apostrophe-asp-net?rq=1)

I guess the question should be how does one add unescaped javascript code to an asp.net button?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok,

I feel kind of dumb, because after experimenting a bit, it appears that although ASP.Net 4.0 renders differently than ASP.Net 2.0 -- the code was actually still working.  That is the button IS disabled -- it just never APPEARS that way.

The problem was when the button was disabled via javascript, there was no visual clue that it was happening, ie: the button did not appear "greyed out" as in previous versions.  To confirm this, I changed the prevent_multiple_submits subroutine as follows:

```
private sub prevent_multiple_submits()

dim sb as StringBuilder

sb = New StringBuilder()

sb.Append( "this.disabled=true;this.style.backgroundColor='#EFEFEF';this.style.color='#000000';this.value='Please wait...';" )
sb.Append( Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference( btn_submit, String.Empty ) )

btn_submit.Attributes.Add( "onclick", sb.ToString() )

end sub
```

Now -- when the button is clicked, the button changes to grey (to indicate it is disabled) -- which used to happen under ASP.Net 2.0 AUTOMATICALLY.   Without the color change -- the button never appears disabled (even though it is) -- this is the difference between 2.0 and 4.0 rendering.

Hope this helps someone else.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid this by removing the `prevent_multiple_submits` sub entirely and adding an `onClientClick` attribute to your button:

```
<asp:Button id="btn_submit" text="Submit (Click only Once)" OnClick="process_form" runat="server" onClientClick="this.value = 'Please wait...';this.disabled = true;" />
```

Though I would take it a step further:

```
onClientClick="disable(this)"

<script type="text/javascript">
    function disable(elem) {
        elem.value = "Please wait...";
        elem.disabled = true;
    }
</script>
```

Or using jQuery, remove the `onClientClick` too:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $('input[id^="btn_submit_"]').prop('disabled', true).val('Please wait...');
    });
});
```

Another jQuery solution that hides the button instead of disabling:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var btn = $('input[id^="btn_submit_"]');
        btn.after('<span>Please wait...</span>');
        btn.hide();
    });
});
```

Of course both jQuery solutions are possible in vanilla js, but the syntax is more verbose, you'd have to look it up.

Comment: Hi Jason - thanks for taking the time to answer.  I tried a test using the "onClientClick" code above -- unfortunately, it does not work -- the problem is the submit button becomes disabled and the "process_form" is never executed.  I would prefer an ASP.Net only solution rather than having to resort to JQuery

Comment: Has anyone using ASP.Net 4.0 done this??? Is it even possible WITHOUT using JQuery?

Comment: @user1377587 The first two solutions I gave don't use jQuery. So that's a different issue, where disabling the button causes the form to not submit. After a little research, I'm not sure how your solution worked in the past (maybe that's another difference between 2.0 and 4.0). You could instead hide the button and append a span with text saying "Please wait". I've edited to add that solution.

Comment: Acknowledged -- I was just hoping for a "pure" ASP.Net solution -- thanks again !

Comment: What do you consider a "pure" asp.net solution? Because even your original (2.0) code used javascript.

Comment: Yes -- I meant not having to rely on a third party external library; sorry, new to this forum and I obviously need to be more clear -- but thank-you again for the solutions !!